# How to split the rows to groups with 'group concat' and 'group by' query in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a database table as below.

```
--id-- --name-- --age--
   1     test      10
   2     test      15
   3     test      20
```

And i want to split this table rows with Group By and Group Concat queries. For example,

```
SELECT name, GROUP_CONCAT(age) as ages FROM 'table' GROUP BY name
```

The output of this query as below:

```
--name-- --ages--
  test     10,15,20
```

But I want an output like below. So I want to divide into 2 groups.

```
--name-- --ages--
  test      10,15
  test      20
```

Is it possible? I hope I was able to explain.

Comment: What is the logic behind your requirement?

Comment: I need to make a limited request to a service in a single request. For example with a maximum of 2  'age 'parameters for a name. I can do it with php but I was wondering if it's possible with mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select name, group_concat(age) as ages from (
  select id, name, age, 
    round(row_number() over (partition by name order by id) / 2) as g 
    from t
  ) as t group by name, g;
+------+-------+
| name | ages  |
+------+-------+
| test | 10,15 |
| test | 20    |
+------+-------+
```